# How can I cast (n+n%2) expression to float so it will give me float number after division?

Tags: c++, casting

I am trying to get float number result from this c++ code, but i cannot for some reason:

```
int n = 5;

std::cout << static_cast<float>(n + n % 2) / 2 << std::endl;
```

Console output is 3. Could you explain what I am missing in this expression?

Comment: 6/2 == 3. Output is correct. Did you expect to get `3.000` or something similar?

Comment: please include actual and expected output

Comment: C++ doesn't print trailing zeros by default.

Comment: Add a line before:  "std::cout << std::fixed;". If you prefer seeing the decimal point and zero's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I cast (n+n%2) expression to float so it will give me float number after division?

You can use `static_cast`, as you did in your example.

> Console output is 3. Could you explain what I am missing in this expression?

Your are missing nothing. The cast to float was achieved successfully and 3 is the correct result of `6.f / 2` using floating point division.